# C# DLL Inject is not functioning correctly

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dll-injection

I am trying to make a DLL Injector Windows Form App in C#. When I run the injection on a process (For example Notepad) it doesn't do anything. I am not sure if its the DLL I am using or the way I'm injecting it. I'm very new to c# so if anything isn't clear on what I'm saying please ask.

I am expecting a message box to open saying hello when I inject but it doesn't do that.
I am not receiving any error messages either.

Here is the code for attaching the DLL:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);

        // privileges
        const int PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002;
        const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
        const int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;
        const int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
        const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

        // used for memory allocation
        const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000;
        const uint MEM_RESERVE = 0x00002000;
        const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 4;

        public static int Inject(string PN, string dllName)
        {
            Process targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(PN)[0];

            IntPtr procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, targetProcess.Id);

            IntPtr loadLibraryAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

            IntPtr allocMemAddress = VirtualAllocEx(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

            UIntPtr bytesWritten;
            WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, allocMemAddress, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dllName), (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), out bytesWritten);

            CreateRemoteThread(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadLibraryAddr, allocMemAddress, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            return 4;
        }
```

Here is the DLL being attached to Notepad:

```cpp
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <tchar.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(NULL, _TEXT("Hello"), _TEXT("Hello"), 0);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: well the first thing of note is that you do not check the return values of any of your function calls. YOu are used to c# and expect things to throw, Win32 calls dont throw. YOu must test the return value

Comment: When checking the return values what should I look for that shows an error has occurred?

Comment: read the spec for each call. Ie OPenProcess https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess "If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Comment: In the CreateRemoteThread I got the error code 5. I believe it means access denied. Maybe its something with the permissions I gave it. Any solution to this? The application is running as admin.